# I need to put a link next to a checkbox in XPages

Tags: javascript, checkbox, xpages

I am trying to use a link instead of the checkbox label because I want the checkbox to be ticked when I click the checkbox and something else to happen when I click the link.

I have tried to put the link after the checkbox and inside the checkbox but the checkbox seem to be wrapped in a div causing it to be misaligned

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:panel style="margin:20px">
        <xp:checkBox id="checkBox2"></xp:checkBox>
        <xp:link escape="true" text="Link2" id="link2"></xp:link>
        <xp:checkBox id="checkBox1">
            <xp:link escape="true" text="Link1" id="link1"></xp:link>
        </xp:checkBox>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

This is the resulting HTML

[image]

This is the web page result

[image]

Is there a way I can add an xp:link next to my checkbox?

Comment: Why don't you use checkBox's onclick event?

Comment: Not sure I know how? different things should happend depending on if the user click the checkbox or the label/link

Comment: Oh I see, although it's not the user experience as clicking label changes checkbox value usually.

Comment: Your resulting HTML is not the result of default rendering. There is no div with standard rendering and standard or OneUI theme. The label is next to checkBox if you use XPages "out of the box".

Comment: It is probably the bootstrap theme causing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best would be to use a custom renderer for the checkbox for that the DIV is omitted. Here is a nice tutorial for a custom renderer used with a combo box: http://www.pipalia.co.uk/xpages-2/creating-custom-renderers-for-xpages-controls/

**EDIT**

I made something:
Create a Java class like this one:

```
package org.openntf.bstemplate.renderer;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.context.ResponseWriter;
import javax.faces.render.Renderer;

public class Checkbox extends Renderer {

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(final FacesContext context, final UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        writer.startElement("input", null);
        writer.writeAttribute("id", component.getClientId(context), null);
        writer.writeAttribute("name", component.getClientId(context), null);
        writer.writeAttribute("type", "checkbox", null);
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeEnd(final FacesContext context, final UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        writer.endElement("input");
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeChildren(final FacesContext context, final UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        super.encodeChildren(context, component);
    }

}
```

Add this to your faces-config:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Input</component-family>
        <renderer-type>custom.checkbox</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>org.openntf.bstemplate.renderer.Checkbox
        </renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Use the new renderer type in your checkbox:

```
    <xp:checkBox
        text="Label"
        id="checkBox1"
        rendererType="custom.checkbox">
    </xp:checkBox>
    <xp:link
    escape="true"
    id="link1"
    text="Click me!">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[dojo.byId("#{id:checkBox1}").click();]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:link>
```

Comment: with this approach databinding of the checkbox doesn´t work anymore. What do I have to do to enable it again?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a custom renderer I think it would be easier to play around a bit with CSS. Because this looks like just alignment issue. For instance you could put the content inside a table (Ugly solution alarm)

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><xp:checkBox id="yourCheckbox"/></td>
<td><xp:link text="Click me!" value="http://www.youclickedme.com"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Ofcourse if you don't want to use tables you should try to play around a bit with div's. The problem here is obviously that the container of this checkbox and link is to small to show them both on a single line.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can dabble with CSS to manipulate the DIV itself:

```
div.checkbox {
   float:left;
   margin-right: 10px;
}
```